# Reading from frame buffer object with OpengGLES2 (Angle)

Tags: c++, uwp, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

Programming an UWP app using Angle to run OpenGL ES, I am facing an issue with the basic operation of reading from a frame buffer object with `glReadPixels`. 
Starting from the Visual Studio Template "OpenglES2 Application (Android,iOS,Windows Universal)", I can retrieve the default scene rendering into a memory buffer.

Initialization :

```
void SimpleRenderer::InitFbo()
{
    int buf_size = tex_height*tex_width * 4;
    mReadBuf = new char[buf_size];
    memset(mReadBuf, 123, buf_size); // arbitrary value to detect changes
}
```

Draw function :

```
void SimpleRenderer::Draw()
{

    // drawing calls here
    // (...)

    glReadPixels(0, 0, tex_width, tex_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mReadBuf);
    // success : mReadBuf is updated with pixel values
}
```

But if I just create a frame buffer object, try to draw in there and retrieve the result, `glReadPixels` doesn't return any value, and `glError` returns `INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION`.

Initialization :

```
void SimpleRenderer::InitFbo()
{
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &mRenderFbo);
    glGenTextures(1, &mRenderTexture);
    int buf_size = tex_height*tex_width * 4;
    char*buf = new char[buf_size];
    memset(buf, 255, buf_size);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mRenderTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4,
            tex_width,
            tex_height,
            0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            buf);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mRenderFbo);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            mRenderTexture, 0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    delete[] buf;

    mReadBuf = new char[buf_size];
    memset(mReadBuf, 123, buf_size);
}
```

Draw function :

```
void SimpleRenderer::Draw()
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mRenderFbo);

    // drawing calls here
    // (...)

    glReadPixels(0, 0, tex_width, tex_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mReadBuf);

    // failure : mReadBuf is unchanged

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

***edit -** solved thanks to the comment below. Correct initialization of the texture is

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,
    tex_width,
    tex_height,
    0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    buf);
```

For the record, before it got resolved I was checking the framebuffer status with `glCheckFramebufferStatus`, which returned `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`.

Comment: Done ; sorry, I was looking everywhere but couldn't find the way to validate the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of the OpenGL function [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/) specifies the internal format of the texture buffer.

In the method `SimpleRenderer::InitFbo` you pass `4` to the internal format, which is not a valid parameter. Use `GL_RGBA` instead:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 
        GL_RGBA,   // <-----------------------
        tex_width,
        tex_height,
        0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        buf);
```

Note, valide parameters for the internal format (in OpenGL ES 2.0) are `GL_ALPHA`, `GL_LUMINANCE`, `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA`, `GL_RGB`, `GL_RGBA`.

If you use `glGetError` after the call of `glTexImage2D` you will get `GL_INVALID_VALUE` which is generated if internal format is not an accepted format. In addition, this causes an `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` error (when checking with `glCheckFramebufferStatus`), if the texture is attached to a frame buffer and `glReadPixels` causes a `INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION` error.